Does quantum algorithm guarantee to solve a combinatorial problem?
One of the applications of quantum computing is to solve practical problems faced in other fields, such as combinatorial problems. One route is encoding the problem into a Hamiltonian and then finding the ground state. But does this process guarantee to solve a combinatorial problem?
Let me make the problem clear. It is obvious that many combinatorial
problems can be encoded into the Hamiltonians of a physical system.
However, finding the solution of a combinatorial
problem is not the same as the to find the ground state of the Hamiltonian.
The reason is that the combinatorial
problem is a classcial problem, and its solution is certianly a classical one,
to be concrete, a discrete one, by which i mean, for example, 010101.
But the ground state of a Hamiltonian is in fact a quantum state. If
it happens the ground state is $|010101\rangle$, every thing is OK. A quantum algorithm,
either quantum annealing or QAOA, will ends with $|010101\rangle$ (assuming it was runing perfectly), and the corresponding classical
solution is of course 010101. If the ground state is a linear combination of
the computaional basis, such as $a|010101\rangle + b|101010\rangle$.
in which case, if $a\gg b$, we could also get the right solution with high probabiliy.
What if the ground state is $|000111\rangle + |111000\rangle$ which contains little or no
component of $|010101\rangle$? Does a quantum algorithm give a right solution?
Now suppose a state in the Hilbert space can be expanded in the computaional basis as
$$
|\psi\rangle = \sum_n a_n |n\rangle.
$$
We want to minimize the energy
$$  
E  = \langle \psi |H| \psi\rangle  = \sum_{mn}
a_m^* \langle m |H| n\rangle a_n \equiv \sum_{mn}
a_m^* H_{mn} a_n
$$
If it is the case that $H_{mn} = E_n \delta_{mn}$, the energy
is given by $E=\sum_n |a_n|^2 E_n$, then it seems that
quantum algorithms guarantee to find the right solution.
However, it it impossible that all the computaional base
are the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian. It is also easy to
see that if the ground state is a 'classcial' state, then it must
be that $a_n=1$ for only one certain configuration and $a_n=0$ for all
the other configurations. Let denote the configuration as $0$.
Then, $E = H_{00}$ and $|0\rangle$ must be a eigenvectors of $H$
with eigenvalue $H_{00}$. I think it is not the case for a general
problem. But how is the case that the Hamiltonian derived from
a combinatorial problem is a specific subset of all the Hamiltonian?
In my view, the question is somehow similar to the relation between classical
continuous programming and discrete programming. Therefore,
no guarantee is made that all the continuous programming problems
are integral, i.e., the optimal solution takes integer values. So
i think the answer may be no.
Is there anyone could give me the answer or some references on this field?

I have neglected the fact that the Hamiltonian generated by a combinatorial problem is an Ising model. An Ising model contains only terms like $\sigma^z_i$ and $\sigma^z_i\sigma^z_j$ which are commute with each other.
Therefore, the set of terms in an ising model can be diagnalized simultaneously and the computational base are their common eigenstates.
So the answer is yes if the algorithm is runing perfectly. If there is a general Hamiltionian, the ground state is a linear combination and we need multiple measuments to extract information. However, for the Ising model, it is very likely we are in one of the computational basis.

However, there may be probable that we are in a linear combination of degenerate ground states. I think the algorithm can “automatically” seclect one of them, due to the symmetry of an initail state or possible noises during runing. Comments are welcomed.
